# Using mockito to mock response from a method which returns ByteBuffer

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am writing a junit test for a method inside which I am calling a method which return the ByteBuffer. I am trying to mock the method call but the bytebuffer is still throwing null pointer exception. This is my very first time writing junit tests using mockito.

My function-

```
public void myfunc(){
CallMyClass cl=new CallMyClass();
// getBody() return ByteByffer
final byte[] response = cl.getBody().array();
}
```

Test-

```
@Mock
CallMyClass cl;
public void test_myfunc(){
when(this.cl.getBody().array()).thenReturn("fddf".getBytes())
}
```

I keep on getting null pointer exception on cl.getBody().array() line of code.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are misunderstanding how mocking works.

The standard format of a mock is `when(mock.method(argumentMatchers)).thenReturn(...)`. So in your case the mocked object would need to be returned by `cl.getBody()` for the `when` to work. But clearly that's not what's going to happen given you haven't mocked the return of `cl.getBody()`.

In fact your `myfunc` isn't even passed a `CallMyClass`; rather it constructs one. So there's really no way to mock its return.

The standard testable format of your example would be:

```
public void myfunc(CallMyClass cl) {
   final byte[] response = cl.getBody().array();
   ...
}

@Test
void testMyFunc() {
    CallMyClass cl = mock(CallMyClass.class);
    ByteBuffer buf = mock(ByteBuffer.class);
    when(cl.getBody()).thenReturn(buf);
    when(buf.array()).thenReturn("fdafds".getBytes());
    assertThat(myFunc(cl))...
}
```